# Can i have a state in OS X where there is no default browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, safari, default

I'd like OS X to default to whichever browser is open (i.e. have no default browser) so that links in other programmes don't go off and open a second browser. Is this possible (without copy/paste). An example would be that i'm listening to music in google music in chrome and i click a link in my evernote and/or wunderlist app and safari is called to open; okay most times but not this particular time.

TIA

Pat